# Javascript Greedy Algorithm Making Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm working on the classic "making change" problem, which is highly documented in plenty of other languages, but there's not much out there for it in Javascript. So far, I have this:

```
    var total = $('#total').val();
    var coins = [];

    function makeChange(total, coins) {     
        var remainder = 0;

        if (total % 0.25 < total) {
            coins[3] = parseInt(total / 0.25);
            remainder = total % 0.25;
            total = remainder;
        }

        if (total % 0.10 < total) {
            coins[2] = parseInt(total / 0.10);
            remainder = total % 0.10;
            total = remainder;
        }

        if (total % 0.05 < total) {
            coins[1] = parseInt(total / 0.05);
            remainder = total % 0.05;
            total = remainder;
        }

        coins[0] = parseInt(total / 0.01);
    }

    function showChange(coins) {
        if (coins[3] > 0) {
            $('.quarter').html(coins[3] + " quarter(s).");
        }

        if (coins[2] > 0) {
            $('.dime').html(coins[2] + " dime(s).");
        }

        if (coins[1] > 0) {
            $('.nickel').html(coins[1] + " nickel(s).");
        }

        if (coins[0] > 0) {
            $('.penny').html(coins[0] + " pennies.");
        }
    }

    makeChange(total, coins);
    showChange(coins);
```

However, this seems awfully repetitive and I'm finding that with certain values, it's a penny off. How can I make it more accurate and concise?

Comment: `I'm finding that with certain values, it's a penny off.` examples?

Comment: This question belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Might be better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: There is something wrong with his code so it's fine here. Example 2.21

Comment: Ok - so it seems it works for `0.17` but not for `1.17`

Comment: @MattBurland 0.48 returns 1 quarter, 2 dimes, and 2 pennies.

Comment: @JayBlanchard We have 3 sites, SO, programmers and codereview. lol.. is there really enough of a difference to justify 3 sites? I can see 2, but where does programmers SE differ enough from SO and CR?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: Read the help center on those three sites and you'll see the differences: [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [so](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [cr](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you have a specific question about a bug in code, then SO is the right place. If you have code that works, but want to know how to make it better, hit CR. If you have a general question about programming concepts, design, algorithms or similar, then programmers is the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm finding that with certain values, it's a penny off.

Probably due to [floating-point issues](http://floating-point-gui.de/). And you shouldn't use `parseInt` to convert a number - it's meant for strings.

> this seems awfully repetitive

A loop, with a data structure that represent the different coins will help. You already did something like that for your result: `coins` is an array, not 4 different variables.

```
function makeChange(total, values) { 
    var coins = [],
        epsilon = 1e-5; // this is wrong in general!
    // assume values are ascending, so we loop backwards
    for (var i=values.length; i--; ) {
        coins[i] = Math.floor(total / values[i].val + epsilon);
        total %= values[i].val;
    }
    return coins;
}

function showChange(coins, values) {
    for (var i=values.length; i--; ) {
        var el = $(values[i].sel);
        if (coins[i] > 0) {
            el.html(coins[i] + " "+values[i].name+".");
        } else {
            el.empty();
        }
    }
}

var values = [
    {val:0.01, sel:'.penny', name:"pennies"},
    {val:0.05, sel:'.nickel', name:"nickel(s)"},
    {val:0.10, sel:'.dime', name:"dime(s)"},
    {val:0.25, sel:'.quarter', name:"quarter(s)"}
];
showChange(makeChange(parseFloat($('#total').val()), values), values);
```

Comment: this is great. much more efficient than what i had going. i'm still coming up with errors every once and while with different values - like .45 returned 2 quarters and 2 dimes.

Comment: @Harlow: You're right, my use of `Math.round` was a mistake (it rounded up not only very-near values, fixed now by using epsilon and `floor`); also the [comparison](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) done in the if-statement was still flawed. I just omitted it now…

Comment: For getting around these awful things, you may want to use integers like @MattBurland did. See http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/integer/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to avoid rounding problems is to just multiple your total by `100` to convert your dollar amount into all pennies, then do you conversion. For example:

```
function makeChange(total, coins) {
    var remainder = 0;
    total = Math.round(total * 100);

    coins[3] = Math.floor(total / 25);
    remainder = total - coins[3] * 25;
    total = remainder;

    coins[2] = Math.floor(total / 10);
    remainder = total - coins[2] * 10;
    total = remainder;

    coins[1] = Math.floor(total / 5);
    remainder = total - coins[1] * 5;
    total = remainder;

    coins[0] = total;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t14cwdph/4/

For making your code easier to manage - see @Bergi's answer.

Comment: The first `Math.floor` (around `total * 100`) does need to be a `Math.round`, though!

Comment: No. Your dollars are still floating point numbers - try `Math.floor(0.29*100)`!